# mvc web site publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i want to create a mvc web site not mvc application. I read somethink about diffrence between Web Site And Web Application. And convert it to mvc web site from web application. But i read that web site does not create  dll's at bin folder when publish it to IIS. But when a publish my web site it creates dll at bin folder. I have Added my models and controllers to App_code folder. But when i publish it to IIS i can not see App_Code folder on it. It creates only dll. Advise me please.

Comment: I have done it. Created empty web site. and the configured website folders as in mvc.and include models and controllers to app_code folder. and when i built it it doesn'n create any dll

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a .NET MVC Web Site. All .NET MVC Applications are Web Applications.

Comment: Really? you are saying that there is not any way to create mvc web site?

Comment: but how i can make so that my source code does not compile. i dont want to use dll

Comment: @AEMLoviji - You can't. .NET MVC doesn't support that behavior.

Comment: thanks. but i will wait for new comments see at : http://jon-pilgrim.blogspot.com/2008/10/aspnet-mvc-web-site-template.html

Comment: @AEMLoviji - Good luck with that. It's an un-supported hack that uses components of .NET MVC to add the functionality to a .NET Web Application (notice the lack of use of Models, etc.). Notice the comments to the post of the routing not working properly either...